# Soft Line Breaks in Gnus (Emacs)

Tags: email, emacs

I am using Emacs more and more. I would like to use gnus for email, and I have it set up. The only problem I am having right now is that when I send an email, there are line breaks when the line wraps. Is there a way for the line wrap to be soft?

Comment: I use `global-visual-line-mode` and I do not have that problem. Are you by any chance using `auto-fill-mode`?

Answer (score 0):

elethan pointed out that I needed to disable auto-fill-mode.

Solved it! Thanks!